# Selenium is throwing NoSuchElementException

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to scrape Myntra website. I have stored all the product links in a list. The code is opening each product link in the list, but when I try to extract any info from the loaded page it is giving me an error. Here's my code,

```
enter code here

    import os 
    from selenium import webdriver 
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys 
    from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
    from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\Sandeep Reddy\Desktop\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver") 
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
    options.add_argument('--disable-notifications') 
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\Sandeep 
    Reddy\Desktop\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver", options=options)

    url = 'https://www.myntra.com/men-topwear?p=1&plaEnabled=false' 
    element = driver.get(url) 
    #driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

    inner_pages_list = []

    for i in range(1,51): 
               inner_document = f'//*[@id="desktopSearchResults"]/div[2]/section/ul/li[{i}]/a' 
               inner_page = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(inner_document) 
              for inner_pages in inner_page: 
                         inner_pages_list.append(inner_pages)

    product_brand = [] 

   for i in (0,len(inner_pages_list)):
                page = inner_pages_list[i]
                page.click()
               time.sleep(10) 
               title = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//* 
               [@id="mountRoot"]/div/div/div/main/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/h1[1]')
               break
```

Comment: See https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html - you need to incorporate wait calls instead of having time.sleep(10)

Comment: I've tried using waits but the problem still remains the same

Comment: What's the error ?

Comment: NosuchElementException

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot of your page showing the DOM and the element that it's failing to locate.

Comment: Sorry @auburg I'm unable to post a screenshot but i will post a link of the webpage,

Comment: https://www.myntra.com/shirts/highlander/highlander-blue-slim-washed-denim-casual-shirt/1265399/buy . This is the url of the webpage. I'm looking for the name of the brand and a few other elements, but I'm not able to locate any of them. And also I'm getting a TimeoutException  when I use waits